# Regular expression doesn't quite work

Tags: php, regex

I have created a Regular Expression (using php) below; which must match ALL `terms` within the given string that contains **only** `a-z0-9`, `.`, `_` and `-`.

My expression is: `'~(?:\(|\s{0,},\s{0,})([a-z0-9._-]+)(?:\s{0,},\s{0,}|\))$~i'`.

My target string is: `('word', word.2, a_word, another-word)`.
Expected `terms` in the results are: `word.2`, `a_word`, `another-word`.

I am currently getting: `another-word`.

**My Goal**

I am detecting a MySQL function from my target string, this works fine. I then want all of the fields from within that target string. It's for my own ORM.

I suppose there could be a situation where by further parenthesis are included inside this expression.

Comment: Hint: `{0,}` is the same as `*`.

Comment: Can any of the terms in the parenthesis be quoted, or only the first one? Can there be an arbitrary number of quoted terms? Maybe you could show us a couple more examples of your input.

Comment: Also, do you need to handle nested parentheses? Will all parentheses always be correctly balanced? Can there be parentheses inside quoted strings? Can there be (escaped or other) quotes inside quoted strings? If you want a regex to handle this, you need to address these issues.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit your question, however the edits have not clarified that much. For example, `word` within quotes does satisfy the rules you specified.

Comment: I hope my latest revision has improved the confusion between my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you have a list of comma-separated terms and wish to find only the ones which satisfy `[a-z0-9._\-]+`. If so, this should be correct (it returns the correct results for your example at least):

```
'~(?<=[,(])\\s*([a-z0-9._-]+)\\s*(?=[,)])~i'
```

The main issues were:

- $ at the end, which was anchoring the query to the end of the string
- When matching all you continue from the end of the previous match - this means that if you match a comma/close parenthesis at the end of one match it's not there at match at the beginning of the next one. I've solved this with a lookbehind (`(?<=...`) and a lookahead (`(?=...`)
- Your backslashes need to be double escaped since the first one may be stripped by PHP when parsing the string.

**EDIT:** Since you said in a comment that some of the terms may be strings that contain commas you will first want to run your input through this:

```
$input = preg_replace('~(\'([^\']+|(?<=\\\\)\')+\'|"([^"]+|(?<=\\\\)")+")~', '"STRING"', $input);
```

which should replace all strings with '"STRING"', which will work fine for matching the other regex.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response, nice to understand the regex better than I did.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using of regex is overkill. In this kind of text you can just remove parenthesis and explode string by comma.

Comment: Correct. Use the regex `([^)]*)` to match the entire parenthesised part of the string, then use plain old string functions - `explode` and friends - to do the rest.

Comment: What if a comma occurs within a quoted string?

Comment: Oh well, he should know what can appear in his string, not me. My point is to avoid regex if you can.

Comment: Yes, but if commas could appear in the strings, regex would be the preferable solution, IMO. But you're right, the problem is ill-defined and therefore currently unanswerable.

Comment: I have updated the question. I also don't really like iterating on exploded string inside an iteration, there could also be commas inside the quoted string, and spaces before/after the commas may/may not exist also.